# How to access route params from react-router-dom using Typescript? Ex: `/some-route/:slug`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Taking this example route which takes a route param `slug`:

**ROUTES.ts**

```
export const SOME_ROUTE = `/some-route/:slug`;
```

And this `<Switch>` component that will render `<Route>`'s.

**AllRoutes.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import * as ROUTES from "@routes/ROUTES";

interface AllRoutes {  
}

const AllRoutes: React.FC<AllRoutes> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering AllRoutes...");

  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.SOME_ROUTE} component={MyComponent}/>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default AllRoutes;
```

And now from the rendered component:

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface MyComponent extends RouteComponentProps {
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponent> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering MyComponent...");

  console.log(props.match.params.slug);  // TRYING TO ACCESS THE `:slug` ROUTE PARAM

  return(
    <HomePage/>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**QUESTION**

I get an error saying that the `slug` property does not exist. Even though it 100% exists, 'cause the value gets logged. But Typescript is unaware of it.

Do I need to manually extend the `RouteComponentProps` to add that `props.match.params.slug` property?

[image]

The `routeProps` (`history`, `match`, `location`) are present as you can see from the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you supply the expected parameters? Like `RouteComponentProps<{ slug: string }>`, presumably. Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50047977/3001761.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Something like this: `interface MyComponent extends RouteComponentProps<{slug: string>}` ? Won't I be overwriting other stuff by doing this?

Comment: Overwriting *what* other stuff? `MyComponent` doesn't define anything else, it seems pointless; just use `React.FC<RouteComponentProps<{ slug: string }>>`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean other stuff defined in `RouteComponentProps`, that comes from `@types/react-router-dom`.

Comment: What other stuff? What do you think the generic is for if *not* specifying the parameters? Look at the definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a047ceb2643f2defd7f7a35aa13c6d00b49de154/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L69-L78.

Comment: @jonrsharpe still on a learning curve here.. but my concern is that the property I want to add is nested on `match > params > slug`.

Comment: And `match.params` is exactly what the first generic type is used for. Please read the dupe and try it out; worst comes to worst, you can undo the change.

Comment: But there are other properties under `match`. Like `isExact`, `params`, `path` and `url`. how can I extend `params` only?

Comment: ...so what? The first generic type argument only gets applied to `match.params`. If you don't believe me, or anyone on that dupe, and can't just try it out for some reason, look at the definitions I linked to, see where that generic parameter gets applied; see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html if you're unfamiliar with generic types.

Comment: You are right, it works. I was testing since you've first mentioned, but I forgot that I trying it on by using the `useParams` hook. Which is a different situation. Thanks a lot for your help. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd suggest just deleting the question; it's answered on the dupe and that was easy enough to find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ReactJS trying to get params but I get property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047977/in-reactjs-trying-to-get-params-but-i-get-property-id-does-not-exist-on-type)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the help of the comments and these other contents:

- [In ReactJS trying to get params but I get property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50047977/3001761)
- And this article: [Using typescript to write react-router 5](https://programming.vip/docs/using-typescript-to-write-react-router-5.html)

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface RouteParams {
  slug: string
}

interface MyComponent extends RouteComponentProps<RouteParams> {
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponent> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering MyComponent...");

  console.log(props.match.params.slug);

  return(
    <HomePage/>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**useParams()**

And also using the `useParams()` hook:

```
interface RouteParams {
  slug: string
}

const params = useParams<RouteParams>();
```

Comment: It looks like the link differs from how you are using useParams(). Sorry new to hooks. Where do you put that?

Comment: @BBaysinger You can import `useParams` from `react-router-dom`. [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Comment: I got the import. Where do put the declaration?

Comment: @BBaysinger either in a `d.ts` file or any `.ts` file where you see fit. Export it and then import it wherever you need to use it. Use it like in the example from the answer: `const params = useParams<RouteParams>();`