# TypeScript error after upgrading version 4 useParams () from react-router-dom Property 'sumParams' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-dom

I get a typeScript error after upgrading to  version 4
Used in useParams ()  from react-router-dom

`"typescript": "^4.0.2"`

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { sumParams } = useParams();
```

```
Property 'sumParams' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

The project worked great and only after the upgrade does it throw an error

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`useParams` is generic. You need to tell typescript which params you are using by specifying the value of the generic

There are several ways to solve this

**This is my favorite way**

```
const { sumParams } = useParams<{ sumParams: string }>();
```

But there are a few more ways  (:

OR

```
interface ParamTypes {
  sumParams: string;
}
```

Then in your Component

```
const { sumParams } = useParams<ParamTypes>();
```

OR

add any type without interface

```
const { sumParams } : any = useParams();
```

Note: that this way you will not be able to set it as a string

OR

More option for [keemor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64027431/9161478):

```
const { sumParams } = useParams() as { 
  sumParams: string;
}
```

Comment: do you know what changed between TS versions to cause this to become an error? I couldn't find anything in the change log that suggested this would change.

Comment: Update: I did a binary search through typescript versions on npm, and this started becoming an issue between version 4.0.0-dev.20200624 and 4.0.0-dev.20200625. You can check out the differences between those versions here: https://diff.intrinsic.com/typescript/4.0.0-dev.20200624/4.0.0-dev.20200625

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did: const { sumParams } : any = useParams();
Still getting used to typescript, so far, I am just not seeing the advantage of forgoing an elegant, dynamic language like JS in favor of the convoluted TS, but maybe I will get it one day...

Answer (score 17):

Another option is:

```
const { sumParams } = useParams() as { 
  sumParams: string;
}
```

Comment: hi  @keemor I gave you a vote and also quoted you in my answer

Comment: It is not good since you simply force a type assertion. Use generic approach of `useParams<TS type here>()` function. It will allow the TS compiler infer your type on the left-side.

Answer (score 6):

To make it function as before, just add ":any"

```
const { sumParams } : any = useParams();
```

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of the router, generic is changed from object to union of strings.

```js
const { param1, param2 } = useParams<'param1' | 'param2'>();
```

Current `useParams` type in the `react-router` types looks like this:

```js
export declare function useParams<Key extends string = string>(): Readonly<Params<Key>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type ParamTypes {
  sumParams: string;
}

const { sumParams } = useParams<ParamTypes>()
```

this would be the clean approach to take

or

```
const { sumParams } = useParams<{[key: string] : string}>()
```

with this approach, you can get as many as param you want without declaring individually

Comment: This is already the second suggestion in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can also access the `params` from `useRouteMatch` if you already have it imported in your file

```
const curRoute = useRouteMatch();
// @ts-ignore
let sumParams  = curRoute.params.sumParams
```

Comment: useRouteMatch will match the query parameters followed by the target path param, not recommend using this way.